# Laravel Save multiple images in multiple fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

So I have a table called 'images' and inside it I have fields in database like 'image1''image2' etc.

Now, the user is uploading each image individually so in a form there are 8 fields for uploading 8 different images, however how do I save this server side? I know how to upload 1 image but how can I do it for multiple images?

Here's my code so far and I am getting these errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gallery' of undefined

and

> POST http://localhost:8000/gallery 404 (Not Found)

Controller:

```
    public function gallery(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('gallery'))
    {
        $image = Input::file('gallery');
        $files = count($files);
        $uploadcount = 0;
        foreach($files as $file) {
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('gallery/' . $filename);
        $image_path = ('gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->fit(60, 51)->save($path);
        $uploadcount++;
        $file = $request->file('gallery');
        $session = session()->get('key');
        $gallery = new Image();
        $gallery->image1 = $image_path;
        $gallery->business_id = $session;
        $gallery->save();
        return ['url' => url('gallery/' . $filename)];
        }
    }
```

AJAX:

```
function submitGallery() {
    var fd = new FormData($(".upload_gallery")[0]);
    fd.append('img', $('.img'));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/gallery',
        data: fd,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".images").attr("src", data.url);
            $('.messages').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Image Uploaded!<div>');
            $(".alert-success").fadeOut(5000);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON; //this will get the errors response data.
            //show them somewhere in the markup
            //e.g
            var errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
            errorsHtml += errors.gallery[0]; //showing only the first error.
            errorsHtml += '</div>';
            $('.messages').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">File type not supported! Use files with image extension only!<div>'); //appending to a <div id="form-errors">
            $(".alert-danger").fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Blade:

```
 <div id="gallery" class="sortable">
                        <form class="upload_gallery" action="{{ action('BusinessController@gallery') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div id="image1" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image2" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image3" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image4" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image5" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image6" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image7" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
        <div id="image8" class="image-gallery">
                        <img class="images" src="#" />
                            <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />
                        </div>
                    </form>     
    </div>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('gallery', 'BusinessController@gallery');
```

Of course if you know of a better approach to do this than mine, please tell me I am open to suggestions

Comment: Did you try with a multiple input ? `<input type="file" name="gallery" multiple>`

Comment: Otherwise I know a very good plugin with a panoply of events and methods that you could appreciate [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Comment: it's all good but it doesn't tell me how to upload multiple images to multiple fields in database

Comment: image input fields are compulsory or optional ?

Comment: they are optional user is not required to upload images

Comment: I think you have problem with base_url. change your line like : `base_url+.'\gallery'`

Comment: I am sure the url is correct look at the route, route is gallery so localhost:8000/gallery however the error says it doesn't exist

Comment: I think to store the images you will need a one to many relationship [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: I do have one to many relationship

Comment: Give them an index by []  <input style="width: 100%;height: 100%; opacity: 0;" name="gallery[]" id="gallery" class="img" data-input="false" type="file"  data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="submitGallery();" />